# Hola tengo que usar un input para filtrar una consulta de un api como lo puedo hacer

Tags: javascript, html

```
const fetchCharacter = (quantity) => {
  fetch(`http://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me/quotes?count=${quantity}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      createCharacterCards(data);
    })
}

fetchCharacter(10);

const createCharacterCards = (data) => {
  let cards = "";
  const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");

  data.forEach((item) => {
    cards += `
      <div class="section_personajed">
        <div class="section_tarjeta">
          <img src="${item.image}">
          <div class="info_section">
          <h4 class="section_nombre">${item.character}</h4>
          <small>${item.character} Dice: </small>
          <p>${item.quote}</p>

        </div>
        
        </div>
  
    `;
  });

  grid.innerHTML = cards;
};
```

> necesito buscar algo en espesifinco con un imput dentro de la api para un ejercicio de mi curso pero no entiendo como tengo el impurt y con ese input puedo filtrar lo que biene de api o consultar segun el dato que se ingrese

Comment: Cual input? necesitas filtrar exactamente que? Especifica mejor tu pregunta y agrega todo el código relacionado a ella

Comment: Ammmm aqui en tu ejemplo que diste el 10 es un ejemplo como si hubieras puesto 10 en el input?